# Am I required to pay UK/ USA Visa fees if I have a German residence permit?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, europe, germany, visas-on-arrival

Here is the situation. I am non-european but staying in Germany with a Residence permit. I can visit all Schengen listed countries with no issue. Assuming that I would want to travel to a non-Schengen country e.g. UK or USA, can I use my residence permit to travel there or am I required to apply as a citizen of my country? Assuming Germans are not required to pay Visa fees to that country, will I have to pay since I only have a residence permit? Third case, Europeans can fly directly to the airport of some countries and apply for a visa from there. In some other countries, you are required to book a Visa appointment at the embassy, which may be granted or not. Does that apply for one with a residence permit?

Comment: Countries that will honour a residence permit in lieu of a visa are sovereign states and not governed by a single rule, so your question can only be resolved on a country-by-country basis.  Overall based upon what  you wrote, applying for a visa-on-arrival depends upon the person's passport and not the presence or absence of a residence permit.  Good question at the root, but too broad in its current state. Close voting until your question is narrowed down to specifics.

Comment: I don't exactly get how the question is general when examples are stated. I guess a general answer would however also suffice, the goal was to know the benefits of a residence permit and if it comes into play in a situation where the citizens do not have to pay Visa to travel to a specific country.  I however changed the title, I hope that makes it a little bit more clear.

Comment: I can think of *several* cases where a person with a German residence permit would not need a visa to a locale outside of Schengen, or alternatively get a visa-on-arrival; but my comment is merely an advisory that your question could attract higher quality answers than those given so far if it focused on specifics.

Answer (score 3):

A residence permit does not make you a citizen, and other countries visa requirements are almost universally based on the *citizenship* of the traveler. So you need to apply for the same visas that everyone else with your nationality do -- except for very few and unsystematic exceptions.

The Schengen rule that a residence permit from one member implicitly works like a short-stay visa for the others is one of these specific exceptions. Another exception is that having a residence permit from an EU country can under some conditions qualify you for visa-less *transit* through the UK even if your nationality is one that would otherwise need it.

But unless you know that a specific exception of that kind applies to you, the safe bet in general will be that there isn't one.

Answer (score 2):

You asked a general question, and the *very* general answer is that you have to apply as a citizen of your nation, but you will mention the residency in Germany.

The German residence permit may *help* to get the visa, but you still need one.

There is a short list of countries that will allow entry to people with a Schengen visa without being part of the Schengen system, e.g. Macedonia.